# How do I link a different controller id variable 'car' to a parent header/link subject?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures

I am trying to make it so that when you click the corresponding subject you are taken to the correct sub section which is on a different controller. Basically the subject controller/model is something like the Mercedes Benz, I want it so when you click that subject you are taken to a page on 'car' controller to view active posts or discussions related to that subject.

subject controller class:

```
def index
  @subject = Subject.all
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
end


end
```

subject index:

```
<h2>Choose Your Car Model</h2>
<dl>
<% @subject.each do |subject| %>
  <dd>
    <a href="<%=car.name %>"><%= subject.name %></a><br />
  </dd>
<% end %>
</dl>
```

error message when viewing subject index:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SubjectController#index

Couldn't find Car without an ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the `index` method does not receive the `:id` parameter, but the `show` method does. If you're using nested resources, you may be looking for the `:car_id` parameter instead:

```
def index
  @subject = Subject.all
  @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
end
```

Always check your `log/development.log` to see what the contents of `params` is as well as checking that the route is defined properly with `rake routes`.